# Changing default Content-Type in SOAP body through WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have created a web service using Axis2 and I want to change the Content-type of my response from  text/xml; charset=UTF-8 to text/xml; charset=utf-8.

Only when I send the Content-type as text/xml; charset=utf-8 in request header, it returns corretly. But in my case, I don't have that flexibility. So, I need to find a way to change th default Content-Type to text/xml; charset=utf-8.

Can some one give an idea on how to change this?

I have tried below like options but no any luck.

WSDL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="GradeTenMathService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema>
            <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" schemaLocation="Math.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="AdditionResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="AdditionRS" element="tns:AdditionResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="AdditionRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="AdditionRQ" element="tns:AdditionRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DevisionResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="DevisionRS" element="tns:DevisionResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DevisionRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="DevisionRQ" element="tns:DevisionRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="GradeTenMathPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="Addition">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:AdditionRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:AdditionResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Devision">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DevisionRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DevisionResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="GradeTenMathBinding" type="tns:GradeTenMathPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Addition">
      <soap:operation soapAction="Addition" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content part="Addition" type="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:content part="Addition" type="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Devision">
      <soap:operation soapAction="Devision" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="GradeTenMath">
    <wsdl:port name="GradeTenMathPort" binding="tns:GradeTenMathBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/axis2/services/GradeTenMath"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you set `options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.Constants.Configuration.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "utf-8");` on the [client's options](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html#getOptions())?